# How do you keep Button from shrinking height when width is increased inside a Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button tag inside a div on my website, and when a user hovers over it it increases in width like this so it gets a nice looking effect.

```
    btn.onmouseover = function(){this.style.background =  "#07334f"; this.style.width = "100%" ; this.style.right = "4%"}
    btn.onmouseout = function(){this.style.background =  "#123f5b"; this.style.width = "90%" ; this.style.right = "-0.35%"}
```

However, when the text inside this button is just the right length and the width is increased the text go from two lines to one and create a ugly style.

Im wondering if there is a way to keep the text from going from two lines to one when the width is increased

the text inside the button will go from this

```
text inside
button
```

to something like this on one line making the button size shrink, and distorting the look making it weird for a user to interact with because it resizes on mouse over

```
 text inside button
```

Answer (score 1):

Is btn an input element of type=button?

Instead you could use a button tag, which supports line breaks within the text.

```
<button>text inside<br />button</button>
```

Alternatively just use an a tag and style it like a button.

Comment: it's the mouseover action that messes up the input inside i think i fixed it by using this     btn.onmouseover = function(){let h = this.getBoundingClientRect().height; this.style.width = "100%" ; if(h != this.getBoundingClientRect().height){this.style.height = h + "px"};  this.style.right = "4%"}